# In Rundeck how to debug if the values from Options are being passed to the remote command as desired?

Tags: rundeck

How to debug if the values selected from Multi-valued Options are being passed to the remote command, as desired?? [space separated values being passed to sh script]

Answer (score 0):

That values are options, you can check if the $RD_OPTION_MYOPTION environment var is passed to your remote node, you can write a simple script like `echo $RD_OPTION_MYOPTION` to check if those values are passed.

Consider [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command) to work with remote options over SSH.

Comment: Used the inline script option and tried to echo, values are blank. How to fix this?

Comment: You can run the job in "debug mode" to check what happens at the moment of pass the RD_OPTION_XXX  to your remote node. Try it out. You need to configure your ssh server to accept RD_* environment variables: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command

Comment: I was wrongly using ${option.myoption} in inline script to echo values whereas i was supposed to echo $1 bcos option values are passed as command line arguments...Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Amazing! Good news then.